# get backup file from wordpress database in x days

Tags: posts, database, backup, phpmyadmin

I have a wordpress website with so many posts and custom fields located in meta table. What I have to do is to make backup from each 30 days (for posts and postsmeta table) and append it to my last backup in my computer. Is it possible? How?

Note: the number of posts is 400k.

Comment: It is possible but you are much better with server level scripting that with WordPress itself. Do you have root access (sudo) to your server?

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes I have access

Comment: I don't really know what you have to work with but I'd write a shell script locally to `ssh` into the server, copy the database, and `scp` to a local machine. There are many, many variants though. Not really WordPress realted however.